# Share content on my Google+ PAGE with ADDTHIS

Tags: wordpress, google-plus, addthis

I am trying to post some Wordpress article directly on my google+ page with addthis, but it always post them on my Google profile.

I just can add a comment, remove extract and photo, and choose my share list, but I can't choose where I want to post it[image: share on g+ page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [addthis support forum](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/576638-google-share-buttons-don-t-share-to-google-pages) they say it is not possible:

> Unfortunately this is a limitation of the Google+ button, not of
>   AddThis. We're not aware of any way to share to Google+ business pages
>   yet.

The way I do it is to copy the URL link of the article I want to share and then go to my Google+ page and paste that link there.

Comment: indeed that's what I do too :/ thank you for the link who confirm my fear

Answer (score 0):

You should use an approved third party solution for posting to Google+ Pages. See the list at http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html